App Intent snippet view does't able to fetch color for xcassets
I have an existing app in which we have implemented AppShortcuts. The snippet view works fine in iOS 17 while in iOS18 beta, it doesn't able to fetch color from xcassets. If we use system colours or UIColor it's working fine.
Error: No color named 'colorBlack' found in asset catalog for
Working with this
Color(uiColor: UIColor(named: "colorBlack")!)

Submit as a bug report

Already posted in Apple Developer Forums

That isn’t a bug report use feedback assistant
